# Merge the HTML table called with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I combine this table?
Automatically adds the label `"</tr> </table>"` to the end of the table I call with Ajax
Is it possible to prevent this?

index.php

```
<table border="1" width="40%" id="dynamic_content">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="application/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        method:"POST",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The proper structure of a table is `table -> tbody -> tr -> td`; to add data to a table you should append `<tr>`s to `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code like this

```
    <div id="dynamic_content_div">
        <table border="1" width="40%" id="dynamic_content">
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    $.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            success:function(data)
            {
            $('#dynamic_content_div').html("<table border=\"1\" width=\"40%\" >"+data+" <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>");
            }
        });
```